# How to do text search in Mongoid

Tags: mongoid

How can I do this query in Mongoid?

```
db.users.find({ $text: { $search: "Something" } }, { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
```

I tried doing:

```
User.where('$text' => { '$search' => "Something" }, score: { '$meta' => "textScore" }).entries
```

But I get a `failed with error 17287: "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $meta”`

Hope you can help.

Thanks

Comment: Would you by any chance have a solution for that now? I've been looking around for quite some time now and I cannot find any answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a great answer but there is a monkey patch available that does work.  Here is a link to the GitHub comment with the code to use:

https://github.com/mongoid/moped/issues/358#issuecomment-81156032

Comment: so is this still not available without hacks?